# How many icons can I have on my flair?

Tags: discussion, support, combined-flair

So, recently, perhaps out of sheer boredom, I have decided to go around and collect scores of > 200 on different SE websites. Some I have gotten reputation through answers, some through questions, and, in the case of skeptics, I got the last 20 points for editing out people's mistakes (because I'm just not that skeptical).

This does leave me wondering though, how many of these sites will give me icons on my flair?

---

And now, your obligatory [moment of Zen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_IwzZYRejZQ).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Taking a look at [Jeff Atwood's insane flair on his blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/) it appears that you can have up to 7.  Likely the top 7 accounts reputation wise.

Comment: Yep, 7 indeed: http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/22973.png :)